# Make AcroFields(iTextSharp) are non editable and set bold

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to populate the data to PDF Templates, which is created in OpenOffice.
it populating fine, I'm getting proper PDF, But that is coming editable mode. I want **non-editable PDF**. And also make **some rows BOLD( by Program)**. below is my snippet code.

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
//loop
fields.setField("Desc_", "HILINSKI, MARK");
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to form to be editable, use form flattening as is done in the [`FillDataSheet`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=122) example. Add this to your code:

```
fields.setGenerateAppearances(true);
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```

If you want to change the font of specific fields, use the `setFieldProperty()` method to change the `"textfont"` as is done in the [`TextFieldFonts`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=158) example:

```
BaseFont bold =
        BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
form.setFieldProperty("Desc_", "textfont", bold, null);
```

For more info, read the [official documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book).